# Access denied to user@localhost

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions

As a root user I did this:

```
GRANT DELETE, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, EXECUTE ON dbName.* TO
'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'apassword';
```

In 'dbName' I created a procedure 'proc_name' with definer set to 'user'@'localhost'.

Similarly I create a function 'func_name' with definer set to 'user'@'localhost'.

Now the issue is, I'm able to do select `func_name();` but I'm not able to call the procedure `proc_name()`

When i did :

call proc_name(), I get the below error:

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'dbName'

Any pointers to the solution would be appreciated.

Comment: `SECURITY DEFINER`? or `SECURITY INVOKER`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'proc_name';`

Comment: @RickJames it is a SECURITY DEFINER.

Comment: @RickJames i am able to see the procedure code when i did select * from information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'proc_name'

Comment: Who was the Definer?  And does 'he' have access to dbName?

Comment: Definer is 'user'@'localhost'. Yes he has access to dbName according to the GRANT statement in the question statement

Comment: What kind of access to dbName does the Proc need?  Perhaps more than `DELETE, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE`?

Comment: yes proc creates, drops temporary tables during run time. So do i have to give permissions to CREATE as well ?

Comment: I updated my grant statement to GRANT CREATE, DROP, DELETE, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, EXECUTE ON dbName.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'apassword'; But this did not help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22319/discussion-between-svkris-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rick suggested in the question comments. We need to grant all the permissions, procName expects. In my case, procName Creates and Deletes temporary tables. So, granting CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES permissions on dbName.* did the trick